# Display data on 2 columns depending on a condition

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am working on an angular application. I want to display data on 2 columns, but I want to decide on which column to put a row according to a condition.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let content of Content"> 
    <div class="col-md-6" *ngIf="content.group==='Date'">
        <div>{{content.title}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example the data is split in 2 groups: text and date. I want to place all the data that is in the text group to be on the left column and the data that is in the date group to be on the right column.

Comment: Do you need aligning the data on the group they have?

Comment: Yes, I want all the data that is in one group to be on the left and the rest on the right column

Comment: @AdelaM write CSS which columns you want to align.

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected output view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make some changes so that you can get the exact output:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let content of Content">
          <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="content.group==='Date'">{{content.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let content of Content">
         <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="content.group==='Text'">{{content.title}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will help.